# Need Photoshop help! How to create a bitmap layer!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I need to make a sprite.  I was instructed to make one layer an editable layer and another layer that is a flattened bitmap layer.  Any instructions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sadly I do not.  Basically one layer is supposed to be editable.  The extension i have on my photoshop is going to create a sprite from the bitmapped layer.  I just can't figure out how to create the bitmapped layer.

Comment: What is the extension? It sounds like you just need to have your artwork flattened before using it (perhaps the extension does not process layer effects)

Comment: well right now, i'm basically in a .psd document.  I thought i'd have to duplicate the layer and then somehow modify the second layer to become a bitmap.  Is this even possible?

Comment: photoshop "is" bitmap. Should you by mistake use some vector tools, the layer or image is easily turned into raster, or "bitmap-isised".

Comment: why is this question downvoted?  i'm a newbie at photoshop and needed help.  please justify the downvote whoever you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All pixel layers in Photoshop are "bitmap" layers. Simply don't use any of the vector or type tools and if you do, rasterize them afterwards. Or choose **Flatten Layers** from the `Layer Panel menu` and you are left with 1 "bitmap" layer.

---

Adobe's use of the word "bitmap" in *their application* does not redefine what the word ["bitmap"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap) (see Pixel Storage at the link) actually means. Adobe's menu items are **not** the definition of a term in many instances.

In global terms, "bitmap" merely indicates a raster image or image where *pixel data* is stored as opposed to vector or other forms of image data.

Comment: My copy of Photoshop CC 20.0.5 reserves the word "bitmap" for 1-bit ("depth" if you will) bitmaps. If I create a new 1-bit bitmap in Photoshop, it will then not allow me to create layers. In case anyone else came here wondering the same thing.

Comment: @RonBurk Adobe's usage of words for menu items is often *not* the actual definition of the word. Answer edited.

Comment: The point is that there are conditions under which Photoshop (as ever, with no explanation) refuses to let you create a new layer. One of those is in play if you see Image|Mode|Bitmap is selected. So if someone says they need help creating a layer for a "bitmap" in Photoshop, some finite percentage of the time this will be the problem. IMHO, your version of PS may vary, etc.